# Database resultset to only 1 file with Apache Camel

Tags: database, apache-camel

Just started using Apache Camel, I would like to know what is the best way to create only 1 file containing the result of a SELECT query to a database, returning many rows?
So far I am able to get 1 file per row, I read it's because 1 exchange is created per row.

Thanks!

Comment: You can configure the file to append instead of overwrite. fileExists=append

Comment: And some database components allows to return all the data in 1 exchange as a list.

Comment: Hey Claus, are you talking about <from uri="sql:{{sql.selectSomething}}?dataSource=dataSource&amp;consumer.useIterator=false" /> because it's what I found after posting my question.